# "[BlackBerry NDK Home] Could not locate a required directory 'host' under the specified BlackBerry NDK root path '/Applications/bbndk'"

Tags: appcelerator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

While attempting to set up the Blackberry SDK in Titanium Studio, I ran into the issue that Titanium Studio is out of date...  Evidently this happens a lot, as even their website is several paces behind even their own program.  (I am really disliking Appcelerator at the moment.)  Anyway, Titanium checks to make sure that `host` and `target` directories exist inside of your root Blackberry SDK folder.  However, Blackberry has updated their file struction since this check was put in (I'm assuming?), and the folder names are followed by a group of numbers, so you get the below error:

`[BlackBerry NDK Home] Could not locate a required directory 'host' under the specified BlackBerry NDK root path '/Applications/bbndk'`

In Windows, it's a different path, but basically the same error (this is in OSX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is simple enough.  Just create an alias (in Mac, a shortcut in Windows) for these folders and just name them `host` and `target`.  This fixes the issue.  Unfortunately, there are more to follow, but I figured I would share this since I couldn't find it anywhere else when I searched for the solution.  I hope I set this question/answer up correctly...